# Split One pdf file into multiple pdf according to page numbers with php

Tags: php, pdf

I need a php script to split one pdf file into multiple pdf file, which takes three input inputFilename,number of pages and outFilename.

please help.

Comment: i understand that you are looking for help, but please be known that this site is not suitable for "give me the code" type of questions. i still hope that you will be able to get what you need, happy coding. :)

Comment: This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62794653/12731030

Answer (score -2):

try this [PDFlib for PHP](http://www.pdflib.com/fileadmin/pdflib/pdf/support/PDFlib-in-PHP-HowTo.pdf)

[Some examples](http://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-cookbook/pdfa/import-pdfa/php-import-pdfa/)