# Split PDF into chunks by page range in Php

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

so after browsing through many packages like TCPDF, FPDP, DOM2PDF and many other excellent php pdf packages, I couldn't find this feature in any packages where it allows to split the pdf file by page range. for example I want to split the pdf from page 20-100 or 30-50. or create a pdf from a pdf ranging from page 20-100. so is there any library that has this feature ?

Answer (score 3):

[PDFMerger](https://pdfmerger.codeplex.com/) has this functionality, and I personally enjoy its simplicity.

```
$pdf = new PDFMerger;
$pdf->addPDF('pdf1.pdf','20-100');
$pdf->addPDF('pdf2.pdf','30-50');
$pdf->merge(); // output PDF, you can specify additional parameters here
```

Comment: You should use a native version of [FPDI](http://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/) because the linked PDFMerger class uses an outdated version from 2009! It's not that hard to build a simliar logic with only FPDI.

Comment: I simply changed the FPDI file it references to the latest version and managed to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the combination of  [FPDI](https://github.com/Setasign/FPDI) and [FPDF](https://www.fpdf.org).

```
$new_pdf = new setasign\Fpdi\FPDI();
        
for($i = 20; $i <= 200; $i++){
    $new_pdf->AddPage();
    $new_pdf->setSourceFile("source.pdf");
    $new_pdf->useTemplate($new_pdf->importPage($i));
}

$new_pdf->Output("output.pdf", "F");
```

Comment: Maybe.  FPDI uses a parser that does not play well with some types of pdf compression (and, no, I don't have specifics, just some files that FPDI can't read).

Answer (score 0):

If any other has problems with the pdf version > 1.4 and you want to split the pdf avoid using FPDI or any other php library you can use the below option that works perfect:

https://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2016/01/how-to-split-pdf-with-pdfseparate.html

it is a very simple command line

Split All Pages

```
pdfseparate <source_pdf_file> <name>-%d.pdf
```

Split Selected Pages Only

```
pdfseparate -f 1 -l 3 <source_pdf_file> <name>-%d.pdf
```

Split First Page Only

```
pdfseparate -f 1 -l 1 <source_pdf_file> <name>-%d.pdf
```

Split Last Page Only

```
pdfseparate -f 8 -l 8 <source_pdf_file> <name>-%d.pdf
```

I have tested the command in my local environment using homestead vagrant and in prouction environment with ubuntu 18,16. Works fine and better than gs (ghost script).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   

use setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;
function split_pdf($filename, $end_directory = false)
{
  
       
        $filename='backup_folderinfocommpunjab_2009/'.$file;
  
    $end_directory = $end_directory ? $end_directory : './';
    $new_path = preg_replace('/[\/]+/', '/', $end_directory.'/'.substr($filename, 0, strrpos($filename, '/')));
    
    if (!is_dir($new_path))
    {
        // Will make directories under end directory that don't exist
        // Provided that end directory exists and has the right permissions
        mkdir($new_path, 0777, true);
    }

    $pdf = new Fpdi();

    $pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($filename); // How many pages?
   $new_pdf = new Fpdi();
   $new_pdf->setSourceFile($filename);
    // Split each page into a new PDF
// 3 and 4 is the page no as exp 3 is staring page number and 5 is last page no
    for ($i = 3; $i <= 5; $i++) {
      $new_pdf->AddPage();
        $new_pdf->useTemplate($new_pdf->importPage($i));
    }   
        try {
            $new_filename = $end_directory.str_replace('.pdf', '', $filename).'_'.$i.".pdf";
            $new_pdf->Output($new_filename, "F");
            echo "Page ".$i." split into ".$new_filename."<br />\n";
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        }
    
}

// Create and check permissions on end directory!
split_pdf("filename.pdf", 'split/');
```

?>