# Extract pages of a PDF file to new PDF files in PHP 7.3

Tags: php, pdf

I have a PDF file and I want to create two new files based on the original file. The first new file should get the pages 1, 2 and 4 of the original file and the second new file should get the 3rd page of the original file. What is the best way to do something like this in PHP 7.3? I found an old library [here](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=pdfmerger), but I don't want to add such an old library to my code. On top of that I found some cloud solutions, but that is also not that what I want. Is there no simple "modern" solution for that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29609647/split-pdf-into-chunks-by-page-range-in-php help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [Mpdf](https://mpdf.github.io/) for an equal problem in the past. You can easily create new pdf documents and import existing pages of a pdf by doing following:

```php
<?php

$sourceFilePath = '/tmp/my-pdf-with-4-pages.pdf';
$destinationFilePath = 'output/my-pdf-with-3-pages.pdf';
  
$mpdfConfig = [];
$mpdf = new Mpdf($mpdfConfig);

// $mpdf->SetImportUse(); only necesseray for mpdf >=4 && <8
$pageCount = $mpdf->setSourceFile($sourceFilePath); // number of pages in your source pdf file 

$pageNumbersToImport = [1,2,3];
$pageNumbersToImportCount = count($pageNumbersToImport);

// importing pages defined in $pageNumbersToImport
for ($pageNumber = 1; $pageNumber <= $pageCount; $pageNumber++) {
  if (!in_array($pageNumber, $pageNumbersToImport, true)) {
    continue;
  }
  
    $templateId = $mpdf->ImportPage($pageNumber); // get page content of page number as template of source pdf file
  $mpdf->UseTemplate($templateId); // add page number of source file to current mpdf generated file
  
  if ($pageNumber < $pageNumbersToImportCount) {
    $mpdf->AddPage(); // add empty page
  }
}

$mpdf->Output($destinationFilePath, 'F'); // write new pdf file, with pages 1-3 of source file
```